# `paper` document class: no date, no author(s) affiliation

Tags: article, pandoc, paper

Hello :) I am new to tex in general, and in fact I am using it through
`pandoc` to generate pdf documents...

I posted a question in StackOverflow ([link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47430435/pandoc-to-produce-pdf-with-latex-paper-document-class-missing-affiliation-an)) but didn't get any help,
my problem is the following:

- I use the `paper` document class
- I fill the `date` variable, but `date` doesn't show up in the document
- I fill the `institute` variable, but author affiliation doesn't appear

I switch to `article` document class, I can see the date but no affiliation.

I do not know what to do to get both date and affiliation via the `institute`
variable. I can switch to another document class but I could not find a
list of available document classes and to what it corresponds.

Any help would be appreciated !

**Edit**

Here is the relevant(?) part of the produced .tex document:

```
\title{my super document}
\providecommand{\subtitle}[1]{}
\subtitle{blablabla}
\author{me \and my friend \and my other friend}
\providecommand{\institute}[1]{}
\institute{alien space agency}
\date{\today}
```

I can see title, subtitle, author in the final pdf, but no date and no institute. I don't understand why.

Comment: Can you please add a minimal example?

Comment: @campa thanks for the hint. I tried with `institution` it still doesn't work - but I would be happy to do further investigation ; where did you find the paper class description?

Comment: As far as I can see, the `paper` class doesn't print the date, except if you are using the `titlepage` option. Your `\providecommand` instructions are useless and `\institute` is not used; the class has `\institution`.